# OpenMP in ray-tracing program with two nested for loops crashing

Tags: multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2015, openmp

I am using OpenMP in VisualStudio 2015.
In my Ray-Tracing algorithm I have the following code

```
int x, y;
#pragma omp parallel for private(y)
for (x = 0; x < sWidth; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < sHeight; y++) {

        thisone = y*sWidth + x;

        for (int aax = 0; aax < aadepth; aax++) {
            for (int aay = 0; aay < aadepth; aay++) {

                aa_index = aay*aadepth + aax;

                srand(time(0));

                //anti-aliasing
                if (sWidth > sHeight) {
                    //the image is wider than it is tall
                    xamnt = ((x + (double)aax / (aadepth - 1)) / sWidth)*aspectratio - (((sWidth - sHeight) / sHeight) / 2);
                    yamnt = ((sHeight - y) + (double)aax / (aadepth - 1)) / sHeight;
                }
                else if (sHeight > sWidth) {
                    //the image is taller than it is wide
                    xamnt = (x + (double)aax / (aadepth - 1)) / sWidth;
                    yamnt = (((sHeight - y) + (double)aax / (aadepth - 1)) / sHeight) / aspectratio - (((sHeight - sWidth) / sWidth) / 2);
                }
                else {
                    //the image is square
                    xamnt = (x + (double)aax / (aadepth - 1)) / sWidth;
                    yamnt = ((sHeight - y) + (double)aax / (aadepth - 1)) / sHeight;
                }


                //camera ray
                Vect cam_ray_origin = scene_cam.getCameraPosition();
                Vect cam_ray_direction = camdir.vectAdd(camright.vectMult(xamnt - 0.5).vectAdd(camdown.vectMult(yamnt - 0.5))).normalize();

                Ray cam_ray(cam_ray_origin, cam_ray_direction);

                vector<double> intersections;

                for (int index = 0; index < scene_objects.size(); index++) {
                    intersections.push_back(scene_objects.at(index)->findIntersection(cam_ray));
                }

                int index_of_winning_object = winningObjectIndex(intersections);

                if (index_of_winning_object == -1) {
                    //set the background black
                    tempRed[aa_index] = 0;
                    //cout << tempRed[aa_index];
                    tempGreen[aa_index] = 0;
                    tempBlue[aa_index] = 0;
                    //return color
                }
                else {
                    //index corresponds to an object in our scene
                    if (intersections.at(index_of_winning_object) > accuracy) {
                        //determine the position and direction vectors at the point of intersection

                        Vect intersection_position = cam_ray_origin.vectAdd(cam_ray_direction.vectMult(intersections.at(index_of_winning_object)));
                        Vect intersecting_ray_direction = cam_ray_direction;

                        //color in the points
                        Color intersection_color = getColorAt(intersection_position,
                            intersecting_ray_direction,
                            scene_objects, index_of_winning_object,
                            light_sources, accuracy, ambientlight);

                        tempRed[aa_index] = intersection_color.getColorRed();
                        tempGreen[aa_index] = intersection_color.getColorGreen();
                        tempBlue[aa_index] = intersection_color.getColorBlue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //adding the colors to each pixel
        //average the pixel color
        double totalRed = 0;
        double totalGreen = 0;
        double totalBlue = 0;

        for (int iRed = 0; iRed < aadepth*aadepth; iRed++) {
            totalRed = totalRed + tempRed[iRed];
        }

        for (int iGreen = 0; iGreen < aadepth*aadepth; iGreen++) {
            totalGreen = totalGreen + tempGreen[iGreen];
        }

        for (int iBlue = 0; iBlue < aadepth*aadepth; iBlue++) {
            totalBlue = totalBlue + tempBlue[iBlue];
        }

        double avgRed = totalRed / (aadepth*aadepth);
        double avgGreen = totalGreen / (aadepth*aadepth);
        double avgBlue = totalBlue / (aadepth*aadepth);

        pixels[thisone].r = avgRed;
        pixels[thisone].g = avgGreen;
        pixels[thisone].b = avgBlue;
    }
}
saveimg("scene_anti-aliased_thread_test1.bmp", pixels);
```

I used several different functions from OpenMP. I tried `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp parallel for` with `#pragma omp parallel for reduction()` and `#pragma omp parallel for private()`.

But nothing seems to work. 
When I use the `#pragma omp parallel` just before the `x`and `y` for loops I get a "Microsoft C/C++ optimizing compilator has stopped working".`Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3017   termination test in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form    Ray-Tracing e:\utility programs\vs - c++\ray-tracing\ray-tracing\main.cpp   258`

```
Error   C1903   unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation  Ray-Tracing e:\utility programs\vs - c++\ray-tracing\ray-tracing\main.cpp   258
```

Why am I getting these errors?

When I use the same `#pragma omp parallel` before the `aax` and `aay` for loops it renders the image even slower.
Now I guess that, when I use the `#pragma omp parallel for` in the second two nested for loops it just computes the code several times and that's it. It doesn't do anything.

But I honestly have no idea, I just started playing around with openMP.

Please help with - which OpenMP functions should I use and where should I put them?

Thanks!

P.S. - the code seen is mainly from the online tutorial for making a ray-tracer from scratch. A basic way to make a ray-tracer by Caleb Piercy.

Comment: You have many race conditions such as `thisone, aa_index, xamnt, yamnt`.  Make these private or declare them inside the parallel region. You may have other problems...`srand(time(0));` is suspicious...

Comment: The srand(time(0)) just follows how much time it takes to execute the whole program. I'll try to work with the race conditions

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also note that your code does not crash. Instead your compiler gives you a very specific error message during compilation.

Comment: What is the type of `sWidth`?

Comment: It's a double along with sHeight. I saw that I can use the "#pragma omp parallel for" if it's an int, but when I try to make then into 'int' the image is squished.